# AngularJS, ng-include file not loading

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to include an external html file (*form-to-add.html*) in angularjs page, but I failed to load it into my main page.

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
  <div class="jumbotron w-50 mx-auto">
    <div ng-app="" ng-include src="'form-to-add.html'">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am also removed the 'src' from that line code.

Comment: why are you using `ng-app` on it?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#examples (button `Edit in Plunker` will open editable version)